# Why i am getting HTTP Internal 500 Error??

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I created a Dynamic Web Project. I have Tomcat 8.5 installed to run it.
Here is my code:

SimpleServlet.java

```
package servletPkg;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        System.out.println("hello from get()");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println("<h3>Hello in html</h3>");
    }   
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SimpleServletProject</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>SimpleServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>servletPkg.SimpleServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet> 
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SimpleServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/SimpleServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title> Web  Application</title>
</head>
<body>
Simple Web Application !HELLO
</body>
</html>
```

http://localhost:8080/SimpleServletProject/---upto this it is executing correctly
o/p--Simple Web Application !HELLO

http://localhost:8080/SimpleServletProject/SimpleServlet----here i'm getting HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class [servletPkg.SimpleServlet]

Comment: What does the logs say?

Comment: What is your project's file structure? For example where is "src" directory?

Comment: [1] You need to post the full stack trace for the HTTP 500 error from Tomcat's log. [2] You show the end of your URL that calls the servlet as **SimpleServlet----here**. That's wrong, and I'm guessing that you didn't mean to type that. Can you clarify what URL you are using for your servlet?

Comment: it is executing correctly. i didn't done anything to it but still working. Thankyou